# How to get the records back from two tables with same primary key if any of the other column fields are changed

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

My previous question is very confusing. I am so sorry for my carelessness. Here, I posted my question again with more information.

My table A and table B has same column names(name,id,age,date,class,...) but different number of rows. Table B is a duplicate table of table A and has fewer rows. What I want to know is how I can retrieve the records if they have the same primary key(id) and any of the other column fields (name, age, date, class,...) are different. However, there is one condition. Although the records have same primary key, if only date is changed, records should not be retrieved.Only when the two tables have same primary key, date is different and any of the column fields is changed, the records should be retrieved.

Since there are around 200k records, and around 100 columns, I would like to use advanced SQL, since my SQL will be too long if I use `Select.. from... where`, but I don't know which SQL to use.

`TableA`:

```
name    age  id  date
------  ---  --  ----------
David   11   1   11/01/2014
Claire  16   2   13/03/2014
Max     15   3   20/02/2014
John    14   4   19/09/2014
James   12   5   16/06/2014
```

`TableB`:

```
name   age  id  date
-----  ---  --  ----------
Max    15   3   15/05/2014
Will   14   4   12/04/2014
Bill   12   7   11/04/2014
Paul   11   8   24/12/2013
Kevin  13   9   03/04/2014
```

Output expected:

```
TableA                       TableB

name  age  id  date          name  age  id  date
----  ---  --  ----------    ----  ---  --  ----------
John  14   4   19/09/2014    Will  14   4   12/04/2014
```

Thanks!

Comment: It will be easier to provide solution if you can provide us with some sample data and the expected output.

Comment: Red Gate SQL Data Compare will do just what you are looking for

Comment: @samar Hi, I have added the two sample tables. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to check for all columns writing a where clause for it might be tedious so you can use `information_schema.columns` to get the column names for that table and then using a dynamic query you can check for column differences.

The following might be the solution to your problem.

```
--Simulate your table structure
CREATE TABLE TableA
(
    NAME VARCHAR(100),
    AGE INT,
    ID INT,
    DATE_COL DATETIME
)

CREATE TABLE TableB
(
    NAME VARCHAR(100),
    AGE INT,
    ID INT,
    DATE_COL DATETIME
)

--Data for testing
INSERT INTO TABLEA(NAME, AGE, ID, DATE_COL) VALUES('David',11,1,'01/11/2014')
INSERT INTO TABLEA(NAME, AGE, ID, DATE_COL) VALUES('Claire',16,2,'03/13/2014')
INSERT INTO TABLEA(NAME, AGE, ID, DATE_COL) VALUES('Max',15,3,'02/20/2014')
INSERT INTO TABLEA(NAME, AGE, ID, DATE_COL) VALUES('John',14,4,'09/19/2014')
INSERT INTO TABLEA(NAME, AGE, ID, DATE_COL) VALUES('James',12,5,'06/16/2014')

INSERT INTO TABLEB(NAME, AGE, ID, DATE_COL) VALUES('Max',15,3,'05/15/2014')
INSERT INTO TABLEB(NAME, AGE, ID, DATE_COL) VALUES('Will',14,4,'04/12/2014')
INSERT INTO TABLEB(NAME, AGE, ID, DATE_COL) VALUES('Bill',12,7,'04/11/2014')
INSERT INTO TABLEB(NAME, AGE, ID, DATE_COL) VALUES('Paul',11,8,'12/24/2013')
INSERT INTO TABLEB(NAME, AGE, ID, DATE_COL) VALUES('Kevin',13,9,'04/03/2014')


--Solution Starts from here 
CREATE TABLE #TableCols
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(1000)
)


--since both tables have same columns you can take columns of any 1 table
INSERT INTO #TableCols
(COLUMN_NAME)
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'TableA';

DECLARE @STARTCOUNT INT, @MAXCOUNT INT, @COL_NAME VARCHAR(1000), @QUERY VARCHAR(8000), @SUBQUERY VARCHAR(8000)

SELECT @STARTCOUNT = 1, @MAXCOUNT = MAX(ID) FROM #TableCols;
SELECT @QUERY = '', @SUBQUERY = ''

WHILE(@STARTCOUNT <= @MAXCOUNT)
BEGIN
    SELECT @COL_NAME = COLUMN_NAME FROM #TableCols WHERE ID = @STARTCOUNT;

    IF(@COL_NAME != 'DATE_COL' AND @COL_NAME != 'ID')
    BEGIN
        SET @SUBQUERY = @SUBQUERY + ' A.' + @COL_NAME + ' != B.' + @COL_NAME + ' OR ';
    END

    SET @STARTCOUNT = @STARTCOUNT + 1
END

SET @SUBQUERY = LEFT(@SUBQUERY, LEN(@SUBQUERY) - 3);
SET @QUERY = 'SELECT A.*, B.* FROM TableA A INNER JOIN TableB B ON A.ID = B.ID WHERE A.DATE_COL != B.DATE_COL AND (' + @SUBQUERY + ')';
EXEC (@QUERY);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice play. If you do that for every query execution, it might take longer than necessary. As long as the table structure does not change often (or without control of the programmer), I would rather let the static stuff be static (so just translating the table structure to plain straight SQL).

Comment: @flaschenpost; you are right in mentioning this. Also another way can be to create the query once and then store it in another table. It can then be executed whenever required instead of creating it everytime the SP executes. But maintaining that query in itself can be an overhead whenever the table structure changes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use strcmp() function to compare the string.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#function_strcmp

for example you want to compare name and age from both table then your query should be like below:

```
select * from (select A.*,B.*,strcmp(concat(A.name,',',A.age),concat(B.name,',',B.age)) as diff from TableA A inner join TableB B on A.id = B.id)tablealias where tablealias.diff!=0
```

include the fields in strcmp function that you bother if they change

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create the complete query more or less automated (make a small script which uses EXPLAIN TABLE, goes through the columns, ignores date and makes your select). After each change of the tables you rerun that script.

The faster way is to introduce an hash-column which gets updated on each write: a trigger AFTER UPDATE and a trigger AFTER INSERT calculate an hash of all the important columns (which also requires writing all that columns down, AFAIK), and write that hashvalue into the hashfield. The select then only compares the hashvalue.

That method is also useful if you need a duplicate check, or a UNIQUE KEY. UNIQUE KEYs are very restricted in MySQL, I think 16 or 32 columns is the limit.