# How to import MS Access records into Excel from a primary table and two linked tables?

Tags: mysql, database, excel, ms-access

I have an Access Database with a primary table called SampleInformation (referred to as PRIMARY table below) and two linked tables called BOD_Data and TSS_Data. The link is based upon a primary key named Number.

I pull records from the PRIMARY table into Excel using this query:

```
...
mySQLCall = "SELECT Number, SampleDate FROM SampleInformation _
    WHERE (DATEPART('m',SampleDate) = DATEPART('m',#" & monthToImport & "#)) _
AND (DATEPART('yyyy',SampleDate) = DATEPART('yyyy',#" & monthToImport & "#))  _
    ORDER BY SampleDate"

Set myRecordSet = myDB.OpenRecordset(mySQLCall, dbOpenSnapshot)
...
```

I would like to pull two variables from each linked table into Excel based for each record returned from the PRIMARY table.

It appears from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23210947/1422252) that I might be able to accomplish this through some dot notation such as that used to access linked records in CoreData, but I have not been able to find any example code. This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT Number, SampleDate, BOD_Data.FIELDNAME1, TSS_Data.FIELDNAME2 _
  FROM SampleInformation WHERE …
```

Is this possible, or must I use separate queries with either iteration or some type of record set query?

I apologize for the disjointedness of this question and thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I simply needed a JOIN.

```
SELECT Sample.FIELDNAME0, BOD.FIELDNAME1, TSS.FIELDNAME2 
   FROM SampleInformation as Sample 
         INNER JOIN BOD_Data as BOD 
           ON Sample.Number = BOD.Number
         INNER JOIN TSS_Data as TSS
           ON Sample.Number = TSS.Number
   WHERE …
```

Feeling stupid for missing that!